# does the word sorrounded make sense ? If not what can be alternative ?

Tags: word-choice

He needs to be surrounded by the people of English users to get the elements of usages in English.

Comment: Hey Nuke! Welcome to EL&U stack exchange. _Proofreading_ questions are likely to be closed here, unless you specify _why_ you are asking the question. Why do you think that the use of _surrounded_ in that sentence is right/wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "surrounded" is fine, but the phrase "English users" is weird and the word "usages" is weird.  Here are some ways I might reword your sentence:

> He needs to be surrounded by English speakers to improve his English skills.
>
> He needs to be immersed in a place where everyone speaks English to improve his English skills.

Comment: @David wow.. I couldn't even figure out what the question was, yet your two examples, specially the second one are superb.